# How to update custom customer attribute default value magento 2.X

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes

I created a custom customer attribute for like **payment_term**(textarea) it is blank by default, I need to set a default value in this text area,

Blank value causes much problem with custom code.

Comment: Yes, I created by script,

Comment: No, I placed blank,

Comment: We need to set the default value for our attribute in setup script.

Comment: Yes, In upgrade script we need to put all data or only  'default' => 'Payment Term',   ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50828/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-ram-sipl).

Comment: If you're using Magento 2.1.x, you should create the Ui component to show your custom attribute: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5942

Comment: My version is 2.06

Comment: Did you reindex? I'm in chat now.